# Close prompt for urxvt

Tags: urxvt

Can I get urxvt to prompt me before closing a terminal when it has a process running in the foreground?

This is the default behavior for e.g. gnome-terminal.

I use i3 [that uses the WM_DELETE protocol to handle this](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_closing_windows) if that is relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A perl script did the trick. I ended up with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

sub on_wm_delete_window {
    my ($self, $event) = @_;
    my $CP = `ps --ppid $self->{shell_pid} -o pid= | wc -l`;
    chomp $CP;
    if ( $CP != 0 ) {
        return system("zenity --question --title 'Close window' --text 'Subprocess is running. Really close?'")
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

sub on_child_start {
    my($self, $pid) = @_;
    $self->{shell_pid} = $pid;
}
```

Which does what I want. (It's a modification of [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/397807/289008)) If a sub process is running the user is prompted to confirm that they want to close the window.

Requires `zenity` for the prompt.

Comment: Was it my link that pointed you to that post?

Comment: Yeah I found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be answered on Unix Stack Exchange in the post
[Prevent urxvt window from closing when a child process is running](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/310355/prevent-urxvt-window-from-closing-when-a-child-process-is-running).

I consolidate below the two answers from the above post.
There are two cases possible.

**When using the tabbed extension**

The solution is found in the urxvt wordpress article
[Commenting out one line in the tabbedex extension can keep your URxvt windows from closing accidentally](https://urxvt.wordpress.com/2015/05/12/commenting-out-one-line-in-the-tabbedex-extension-can-keep-your-urxvt-windows-from-closing-accidentally/):

> Locate the following code in your tabbedex extension file. The file is
>   probably located somewhere near `/usr/local/lib/urxvt/perl/tabbedex`,
>   or the equivalent on your system.
>
> This is the Perl code snippet to look for:
>
> ```
> sub on_wm_delete_window {
> my ($self) = @_;
> $_->destroy for @{ $self->{tabs} };
> 1;
> }
> ```
>
> All you have to do is comment out one line, as shown below.
>
> ```
> sub on_wm_delete_window {
> my ($self) = @_;
> # $_->destroy for @{ $self->{tabs} };
> 1;
> }
> ```

**When not using the tabbed extension**

Use the following script, whose file-name let's say is `close-prevent`:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl  
sub on_wm_delete_window {
    return 1;
}
```

Place the script in `/usr/lib/urxvt/perl/` for system-wide availability or in
`~/.urxvt/ext/` for user-only availability, and modify `~/.Xdefaults`:

```
URxvt.perl-ext-common: ...,close-prevent
```

Run `xrdb ~/.Xdefaults` after each modification.

The uxrvt terminal window will now not close when using
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> or the close button.
The `exit` command or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
will still work.